# Find column headers by name and select all data below headers from multiple workbooks and paste the data one below other in master file in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 different workbooks in a particular folder, Each workbook contains only 1 sheet in it.
Each workbook has same format and has about 145 headers on row 12.
This headers has some data below it, please note the data in each workbooks are different and has missing data too so not sure about last row data.
In Master file, i have mentioned 30 headers in row 3 which are needed.
I need a VBA macro which should look for headers from master file and copy the data from 1st file and paste it in master. Once the data is copied from 1st file it should copy the data from 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th file and paste one below another in master file.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try by your own? It is difficult to be helped if you do not show us anything about your real situation. At least some pictures showing the initial situation and the whished one. If you would post a piece of code, we will maybe understand better then only reading your question. Please, edit your question and show us a reproductibile situation. [Minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: You should also better explain what "copy the data from 1st file and paste it in master" means. Should the needed code search for every header of 'Master' (row 1), in the headers row of those 'multiple workbooks' (row 12) and return, if a header match exist, the column range starting from the row bellow the header up to the column last cell? If not, please better describe what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub CopyInMaster()
   Dim wb As Workbook, mWb As Workbook, mWbPath As String, shMWb As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
   Dim folderPath As String, fileName As String, arrHead, lastERM As Long, lastrWS As Long, arrCopy, i As Long, j As Long
   
   folderPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\TestImport\"  'use here the folder path where the workbooks to import data exist
                                                                       'please, take care of the ending"\"
   mWbPath = folderPath & "Master.xlsx"                 'use here your Master workbook full name
   
   'check if the master workbook is open. If not, open it
   For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.fullName = mWbPath Then Set mWb = wb: Exit For
   Next
   If mWb Is Nothing Then
        Set mWb = Workbooks.Open(mWbPath)
   End If
   
   Set shMWb = mWb.Sheets(1) 'if the sheet to be updated in Master wb is not the first one, please adapt the code using its name
   'put master headers in an array:
   arrHead = shMWb.Range("A1", shMWb.cells(1, shMWb.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).value

   'iterate between all workbooks to be used in the necessary folder:
   fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls*")
   Do While fileName <> ""
        If Not fileName = mWb.Name Then 'if the master workbook is not in the same folder, this lines can be eliminated (If - End If)
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileName)
            Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
            'copy each mathing column data:
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrHead, 2)
                For j = 1 To ws.cells(12, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    If arrHead(1, i) = ws.cells(12, j).value Then
                        lastrWS = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, j).End(xlUp).row            'last row
                        lastERM = shMWb.cells(shMWb.rows.count, i).End(xlUp).row + 1  'first empty row
                        arrCopy = ws.Range(ws.cells(13, j), ws.cells(lastrWS, j)).value      'put the range to be copied in an array (to be faster)
                        shMWb.cells(lastERM, i).Resize(UBound(arrCopy), UBound(arrCopy, 2)).value = arrCopy 'drop the array content
                    End If
                Next
            Next i
            wb.Close False  'close the workbook without saving it
        End If
        fileName = Dir()
   Loop
End Sub
```

Please, take care to correctly adapt the necessary paths and 'Master' workbook full name!

It is good to learn, besides the above code, that we here do not offer free coding services. We (usually) only help people understanding their coding problems and learn. So, you should show us what you  tried by your own and better explain what is to be done. Please, understand that I made an exception!

It is also good to know that when placing a question it is at least polite to frequently check it and answer the clarification questions, if any.

After testing it, I would like to receive some feedback. I asked about clarifications and I only assumed that this is what you like doing. If not, please accurately describe what you need against what the code returns.

Comment: @nikolayDudrenov Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it solve your problem?